# SiteUrl config issue, accessing a zend framework project in a sub-folder from a virtualhost subdomain

Tags: zend-framework, apache2, virtualhost

My site runs wordpress as the main CMS in the root folder. In a sub-folder I have a zend framework project which is /account. This is the members area of our website application. I just started playing with sub-domain configurations for allowing users to login from their own custom sub-domain.

In the virtual host configuration I just mapped the sub-domain to /var/www/account the zend folder.

In the zf index.php I have the line below

```
define('SiteUrlUser','http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/account/');
```

When I test connecting to a sub-domain the only way to get it to work is by accessing pages without /account in the URL. What change do I need to make to allow users to login from sub-domains where /account isn't needed? I'm not sure how to configure this correctly. Any help in the zf configuration or apache2 would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Zend Framework are you running?